# how to convert pdf to .txt and .txt to json by using node.js

Tags: javascript

I have a PDF file I want to extract certain fields from the PDF and convert them into .json file. I have looked at a couple NPM packages like pdfjs, pdf2json. I tried many ways that i found throughout my search.i cant figure out how to convert PDF to json file.can anyone tell me how to figure out this.I can able to convert text to json file if anyone can tell the function of PDF to text that also helpful for me..

Comment: the answer depends on the content of the PDF and the required JSON result - i.e. your question is massively too broad

Comment: For the PDF to TXT conversion, you could actually use pdf.js. If you're happy with the JSON format that pdf2json produces, you could also use that, but as it bundles pdf.js internally and doesn't have an own parser, I guess it won't make much of a difference. While pdf.js seems like a reliable solution that handles many PDF glitches and oddities, mind that it is also a very big dependency which may increase your bundle size by ~ 870 kb. There are different builds available though, so you might want to investigate which of them suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

### PDF to TXT

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-to-text

Use it like this:

```
var pdfUtil = require('pdf-to-text');
var pdf_path = "absolute_path/to/pdf_file.pdf";

//option to extract text from page 0 to 10 
var option = {from: 0, to: 10};

pdfUtil.pdfToText(upload.path, option, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw(err);
  console.log(data); //print text     
});

//Omit option to extract all text from the pdf file 
pdfUtil.pdfToText(upload.path, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw(err);
  console.log(data); //print all text     
});
```

### TXT to JSON

https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-2-json

Run the command from command line. Example:

```
node index.js --i=test/test.txt --o=test/output.json --h
```

Comment: my code:     var pdfUtil = require('pdf-to-text');
var pdf_path = "./home/hades3/Desktop/converter/journal.pone.0026738.pdf";

//option to extract text from page 0 to 10 
var option = {from: 0, to: 10};

pdfUtil.pdfToText(upload.path, option, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw(err);
  console.log(data); //print text     
});

//Omit option to extract all text from the pdf file 
pdfUtil.pdfToText(upload.path, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw(err);
  console.log(data); //print all text     
});

Comment: output error   hades3@hades3-OptiPlex-990:~/Desktop/converter$ node stack.js
/home/hades3/Desktop/converter/stack.js:7
pdfUtil.pdfToText(upload.path, option, function(err, data) {
                  ^

ReferenceError: upload is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hades3/Desktop/converter/stack.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

Comment: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3

Comment: @Commercial Suicide what is upload.path in above code